# WIn R, why does range become "Inf" when I apply complete.cases and try to create a new matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to plot a couple of parameters in a dataset.  However, I get an infinity error when I try to plot.

It looks like applying either complete.cases or making a new data frame changes the `range` to `-Inf` and `Inf`.  Why is this?  How do I change it so the ranges are finite numbers and can be plotted?

```
analysis <- function(){

  #input file
  input_df<-read.csv("Book1.csv")

  dput(head(input_df))

  print(range(input_df$Forecast_Error))
  print(range(input_df$YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp))


  #create new data file with forecast errors

  #input2_df <- input_df[,c(10,14)]
  input2_df <- data.frame(input_df$Forecast_Error, input_df$YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp)

  print(range(input2_df$Forecast_Error))
  print(range(input2_df$YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp))


  input2_df <- input2_df[complete.cases(input2_df), ]


  print(range(input2_df$Forecast_Error))
  print(range(input2_df$YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp))

  write.table(input2_df,"test.txt")  

  plot(input2_df$Forecast_Error, input2_df$YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp, main="Toronto Observed Temp vs Forecast Error", 
       xlab="Forecast error", ylab="Toronto observed Temp", pch=19)

}
```

Output:

> source('PeakMissAnalysis.R')
>   analysis()

```
structure(list(Date = c(43191.95833, 43191.91667, 43191.875, 
43191.83333, 43191.79167, 43191.75), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L), month = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), day = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hour = 24:19, Forecast_Error = c(-132.55, 
-141.36, -255.57, -180.2, -461.28, -359.09), YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp = c(-0.2, 
-0.3, -1, -0.7, -0.4, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
[1] -866.75  397.00
[1] -3.4  7.1
[1]  Inf -Inf
[1]  Inf -Inf
[1]  Inf -Inf
[1]  Inf -Inf
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Here is a screen shot of the data
[Screen shot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlxRs.png)

Comment: It's a little hard for me to speculate without being able to access the data you're using. Can you post a link or else share enough for us to replicate the error you're experiencing?

Comment: `range(c())` gives `[1] Inf -Inf` with a _warning_. So you may have no complete cases and `input2_df` has 0 rows.

Comment: Thanks Joseph and Axeman - there are some complete cases, I have added a screen shot of the data - does that help?

Comment: A screenshot of data is pretty useless. We can't copy/paste it, experiment with it, etc. It's not even data *in R*, so there's no way to verify even that your import was successful. Posting `dput(head(input_df))` in your question would be much better.

Comment: Thannks for the input Gregor - is there some site I can attach files to and then post the link to here.  ?  I added dput(headIinput_df)) into the questions.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what's going on. When you create input2_df with

```
 input2_df <- data.frame(input_df$Forecast_Error, input_df$YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp)
```

the names of the new dataframe are *not* Forecast_Error and YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp, they're input_df.Forecast_Error and input_df.YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp; the data.frame function doesn't know what you want to call those variables. Better would be

```
input2_df <- input_df[c('Forecast_Error', 'YYZ.Toronto.Observed.Temp')]
```

Now the new names will be what you expect. This solution worked when I tested it up through the last range statement.